# Show that $S \leq \sup _{x \geq(1+\varepsilon) M_{n}} x^{-1 / r} \cdot x^{1 / r-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} E|X_{k}|^{r} I(|X_{k}|>x^{1 / r}) $

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $1<r<2$ and let $\left\{X_{n}, n \geq 1\right\}$ be a sequence of pairwise independent random tariables
with $E X_{n}=0$ and $E\left|X_{n}\right|^{r}<\infty$ for all $n \geq 1 .$

Set $M_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n} E\left|X_{k}\right|^{r}$,  $$S =\sup _{x \geq(1+\varepsilon) M_{n}} x^{-1 / r}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} E X_{k} I\left(\left|X_{k}\right| \leq x^{1 / r}\right)\right| $$ and let $\varepsilon > 0$

Show that $$S \leq \sup _{x \geq(1+\varepsilon) M_{n}} x^{-1 / r} \cdot x^{1 / r-1} \sum_{k=1}^{n} E|X_{k}|^{r} I(|X_{k}|>x^{1 / r})  $$

My work so far :

since $EX_n = 0$ then $\forall a $ :
\begin{multline*} EX_n = 0 \Longrightarrow EX_nI(|X_n|>a) + EX_nI(|X_n|\leq a) = 0  \Longrightarrow |EX_nI(|X_n|>a)| = |EX_nI(|X_n|\leq a)| \\ \end{multline*}

using this and Jensen's inequality we get :

\begin{align}
S=\sup _{x \geq(1+\varepsilon) M_{n}} x^{-1 / r}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{n} E X_{k} I\left(\left|X_{k}\right|>x^{1 / r}\right)\right| \\
 \leq \sup _{x \geq(1+\varepsilon) M_{n}} x^{-1 / r} \sum_{k=1}^{n} E\left|X_{k}\right| I\left(\left|X_{k}\right|>x^{1 / r}\right) \\
\end{align}

however I'm stuck here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are almost done. Just note that

$\frac{|X_k|}{x^{1/r}} 1_{|X_k| > x^{1/r}} \leq \frac{|X_k|^r}{x} 1_{|X_k| > x^{1/r}} $  since, either $|X_k| < x^{1/r}$, in which case both sides are 0, or otherwise, $\frac{|X_k|}{x^{1/r}} \geq 1$, and if $a \geq 1$, then $a^r \geq a$ for $r \geq 1$.